# Extract Number from String using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, xml, gridview

I have Rss feed using XDocument.Load("Somelink"); I am getting XML output from the server.

```
<item>
    <title>Senior Web Developer</title>
    <link>Some link</link>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">Some link</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[University of UK &lt;br /&gt;Salary: £39,324 to £46,924 pa]]></description>
</item>
```

In description tag i am getting company information and salary, I need only Salary part in that description, How to extract salary from that link.

```
var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                         select new
                         {
                             title = x.Element("title").Value,
                             description = x.Element("description").Value
                         });
```

How to extract that salary from description tag . I want to display that salary in two different labels.

I need output in Grid view Salary from and Salary to. I tried Regex.Match  method its giving only first two digits.

Code :-

```
<asp:GridView  ID="gRss" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
     ShowHeader="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"> 
                     <tr>
                         <td class="info"><%#Eval("Title") %></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td><%#Eval("SalaryFrom") %></td>
                     </tr>  <tr>
                         <td><%#Eval("SalaryTo") %></td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

C# code

```
 List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
        try
        {
            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
            xDoc = XDocument.Load("Some link");
            var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                         select new
                         {
                             title = x.Element("title").Value,
                             description = x.Element("description").Value
                         });


            if(items != null)
            {
                foreach(var i in items)
                {

                  //  string resultString = Regex.Match(i.description, @"\d+").Value;
                    //resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
                    var match = Regex.Match(i.description, @": £(?<from>.*?) to £(?<to>.*?) ");
                    var from = match["from"].Value;
                    var to = match["to"].Value;
                    Feeds f = new Feeds
                    {
                        Title = i.title,
                        Description = resultString
                    };
                    feeds.Add(f);
                }
            }
            gRss.DataSource = feeds;
            gRss.DataBind();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) to extract the salary range.

```
var matches1 = Regex.Matches(descriptionValue, "£([0-9,]+)");   
for(int i=0; i < matches1.Count; i++)
     Console.WriteLine("Parameters >> " + i + "\t" + matches1[i].Value);
```

Here you will have from on first and to on second location of result returned by `Regex.Matches`.

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression `: £(?<from>.*?) to £(?<to>.*?)` uses named capture groups `from` and `to`. With its help needed values are extracted from `description`.

```
var match = Regex.Match(description, @": £(?<from>.*?) to £(?<to>.*?) ");
var from  = match.Groups["from"].Value;
var to    = match.Groups["to"].Value;
```

[Regex Test](https://regex101.com/r/t9fZRL/1)

Edit: Added `.Groups` property.

Comment: I am getting Cannot apply indexing with [] to an epression of type System.Text.regularExpression.Match Exception , I have added C# code in the question.

Comment: That's because it should access the `Groups` property of the `Match` object. Like so: `match.Groups["from"].Value;`